# What is child nameserver and what is use of it?

Tags: server

I need to know about child nameserver, What is it and for what purpose can we use that ?

I have seen an option in whois.com about child name server which has to be pointed out to an ip address, I have tried to use as an subdomain, but I can use subdomain by another way, so basically what is use of that actually ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from a source I found using Google:

> "Child Name Servers are private labelled name servers which are registered with domain registry under your own domain name.
>
> eg. ns1.domainname.com,  ns2.domainname.com
>
> Child Name Servers needs to be registered with registry and also it's A record needs to be pointed to IP address of DNS Server before they can be used as name servers with other domain names. Child Name Servers can be only registered by owner of the primary domain name."

You could use them for a number of reasons; e.g.

- If the parent nameserver is run by a DNS provider, the child nameserver could allow you to host the names in the subdomain yourself ... and update them without relying on the DNS provider's (possibly clunky) APIs.
- Within a large organization it could allow the management of different subdomains to be done by different groups.
- You might do it if you wanted a subdomain to contain dynamic names.

---

> I have seen an option in whois.com ...

I think you might be confused about the purpose of the WHOIS service.  It is purely for *documenting* which people (notionally) control which domains.  To implement a child domainserver, you just need an A record in the parent domainserver that points to the child.